# Confused in behaviour of 2-d array in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
n,m,k=map(int,input().split())
students=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
classroom=[]
count=0
rows=[0]*k
for i in range(m):
    classroom.append(rows)
for i in students:
    for j in range(k):
        if c[i-1][j]==1:
            continue
        else:
            c[i-1][j]=1
            count+=1
            break
print(classroom)
```

`"""
I want to calculate the number of students who are seated in their preferred row(it should vacant for student), in my case 0 is my vacancy and there are n students with their preferred rows( array of n with ith elemnt as preferred row).

Now my input is 5 2 2
1 1 2 1 1
here n=5,k=2(row length), m=2(no. of rows)
array=[1,1,2,1,1](students in the above code)
as per my code classroom will be my 2d array of size 2x2

Now, here logically it should print the classroom [[1,1],[1,0]] but im unable to understand why it is printing the classroom [[1,1],[1,1]]

I have testeed with input 5 2 2
1
so logically it should print classroom [[1,0][0,0]] but it is printing classroom [[1,0],[1,0]]. I have tested this on python 3 .

Please let me know what did i do wrong or what is the concept i didn't understand or what is logic behind this`

Answer (score 0):

This line

```py
classroom.append(rows)
```

appends the same address again and again. Thus when one of them is modified, all the others are modified. That's why the rows of your output are all the same.

Change this line to

```py
classroom.append([0] * k)
```

This ensures that the rows are independent of each other.